# GAE NDB Query to return objects with their respective referenced object's attributes

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I simplified a few of my classes, User and Post.  A user can have [0,many] posts.

```
class User(ndb.model)
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    avatarUrl = ndb.StringProperty()

class Post(ndb.Model):
    """ Model for storing user profile posts """
    postType = ndb.StringProperty()
    text = ndb.StringProperty()
    userId = ndb.StringProperty() #referencing User key
    createdAt = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

I'm looking for a way to: *Retrieve all Post objects posted by User x*.  Is it possible, in a single query, to retrieve all post objects as well as their respective user's attributes?

Pseudo code for what I have now: 
1. Post query where userId = x
2. For each returned post, User query where userId = post.userId
3. For each returned post, union post attributes and user attributes

This is requiring me to perform 1 query for Post objects and n queries for user objects, and my python script is doing a merge n times.  I know there's a better way.  I explored using ndb.KeyProperty in Post instead of a ndb.StringProperty(), but the algorithm was the same and didn't seem helpful.

What's the best way to do this?  Any links to examples or documentation would be helpful.  Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly what you are trying to do then KeyProperty will be better because then you do a batch of gets rather than a set of queries, which will be faster.

Comment: Thanks, @TimHoffman.  I stumbled upon http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868410/how-do-i-use-ndb-keyproperty-properly-in-this-situation.  Is the selected answer what you were referring to?

Comment: Yes, though you can make it more efficient by prefetching all of the entities.  Essentially loop through all the posts, collect the keys and do a get_multi, which is a single round trip rather than multiple gets.  (make sense if you a number of different userid) if all point to a single user then ndb caching will make things efficient.

Comment: Geeze, that's helpful.  Thanks @TimHoffman